# Margin bottom not working on iPhone or iPad

Tags: html, css, ios, twitter-bootstrap-3, margin

I am using the following: WordPress Version: 5.5.1 / PHP Version: 7.4.9 / Bootstrap Version: 3.3

This is the site I am working on: http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au

I am having problems with an **inline** `<li>` display of urls that spill over into several lines (with padding & backing color to make it look like buttons).  I've added a `margin-bottom: 10px;` to the `<li>`, to keep them from getting too close to (touching) the 'button' that appears in the line below it as the list wraps.

The Celebrant Ceremonies website looks like I want it to on:

- FireFox & Chrome browsers on Windows 10 (no matter how small I make the window size)
- Android phone

But when I test it out on 2 iPhones (IOS 13.4.1 & IOS 13.6.1) &  1 iPad (IOS 9.2.1), the bottom margin isn't working on this particular list I want displayed.  On one of the iPhones, I viewed the website using both a Safari & a Google browser, and both have the same problem.

So, from my testing, it appears to be an issue with how IOS (at least on smaller devices) handles the margin-bottom (eg: not specific to just the safari browser).

To see the list that I have created, go to the home page: http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au, and scroll down near the bottom, there are a bunch of gold tag links listed (sorta looks like rounded buttons.)

You can also see them in a sidebar on the funeral page: http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/funerals-celebration-of-life-ceremonies/.

For an example, here is the html coding that displays the list on a sidebar:

```
<ul class="tags-v4 margin-bottom-40">
<li><a class="rounded-4x" href="http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/#funeral-services">funeral services</a></li>
<li><a class="rounded-4x" href="http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/#burial-services">burial services</a></li>
<li><a class="rounded-4x" href="http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/#graveside-services">graveside services</a></li>
<li><a class="rounded-4x" href="http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/#memorials">memorials</a></li>
<li><a class="rounded-4x" href="http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/#celebration-of-life">celebration of life</a></li>
<li><a class="rounded-4x" href="http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/#ceremonies">ceremonies</a></li>
<li><a class="rounded-4x" href="http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/#cremation-services">cremation services</a></li>
<li><a class="rounded-4x" href="http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/#scattering-of-ashes">scattering of ashes</a></li>
<li><a class="rounded-4x" href="http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/#melbourne-marriage-celebrant">melbourne celebrant</a></li>
<li><a class="rounded-4x" href="http://www.celebrantceremonies.com.au/#south-gibbsland-marriage-celebrant">south gibbsland</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the css coding that styles the list:

```
ul, ol {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.rounded-4x {
    border-radius: 20px !important;
}

ul.tags-v4 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.tags-v4 li { 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

ul.tags-v4 a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'kabel_bk_btbook', verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #962838;
}

.textwidget ul.tags-v4 a {
    background: #000000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.col-md-9 ul.tags-v4 li a {
    background: #c5b358 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}

ul.tags-v4 a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'kabel_bk_btbook', verdana;
    background: #c5b358 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.25s ease 0s, transform 0.25s ease 0s;
}

.textwidget ul.tags-v4 a:hover {
    background: #c5b358 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

.col-md-9  ul.tags-v4 a:hover {
    background: #000000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion on what will make the `<li>` `margin-bottom` work on IOS devices without breaking it on all others?

Cheers.

Comment: There is no margin in _any_ browser as far as I can see. Give the inner `a` tags `display: block` and the margin will work.

Comment: Thanks @Turnip, adding the display: block worked on Safari browser. ( I didn't think it did at first, as I didn't see any changes to the display, but after I cleared all history and data for Safari, the margins showed up.)  Note: it didn't seem to work on the iPhone Google browser, however I think that might still be some cache issue.  If you submit a 'answer' instead of a comment, I'll accept it as the answer!